# You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I want to create an angular 2 App with angular cli

I have written in the cmd:

> npm install angular-cli -g

then:

> ng firstngapp

but it show me an error when I write npm start ! 
[image: the error image]

[image: Files image]

I don't understand the problem

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I was in the parent folder.

Comment: Try to run npm bugs firstngapp and see. It will guide you to resolve your problem

Comment: After
**npm install**
you can try closing the project then open again. It worked for me.

Comment: Are you rusty like me? After cloning project... change to project folder and `npm install`

Comment: agreed, you have to run "npm install angular-cli -g ", then "npm install" and finally the "ng XXX"

Comment: Please run "npm update" command. This issue will get when "node_modules" folder missing in your project or only "@angular/core" package missing.

Answer (score 195):

Try to run

```
npm install
```

**in the project folder** (not root folder)

Answer (score 80):

While running `ng serve` **you should be in the app's/project's directory**.

If you run the command in another directory you get the error:

> You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.

Comment: I was depending on "@angular/core" but i was not in the project directory so i was getting that error

Answer (score 16):

Delete your node modules , Check your `package.json` file should have the `@angular/core` and reinstall it with `npm i`.

Answer (score 16):

1. Delete **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file.
2. Then run following command it will update npm packages.

   `npm update`
3. Later start project executing following command.

   `ng serve`

Above steps worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Below steps worked for me:

1) Delete the `node_modules/` folder and `package-lock.json` file.

2) `npm install`

3) `ng serve`

Answer (score 8):

May help you.

- Delete All folders you have created previously
- Create fresh folder
- Then try navigate to that folder from command "cd foldername"
- then try to install "npm install"

This will solve you problem.

Answer (score 7):

from terminal

```
 > cd myProjectPath
 myProjectPath > npm install
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the top answer at the moment - is this a necessary answer?

Comment: Better than the same suggestion above.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is still an issue. I was experiencing the same nuisance with `@angular/cli v1.1.2` on `npm 4.1.2`. I deleted the `node_modules` directory and then went on to updating `npm` (since this was a common cause in the past).

I wanted to upgrade `npm` to `5.0.3` (latest) but since I was using `nvm` it seems to have messed up the libraries. Thus, I reinstalled `node`.

Then, I went with

- `npm cache clean`
- `npm rebuild`
- `npm install` - This one several times, since every time it threw an error with a different package

In the end, every package was fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

the fix for me was

```
npm link
ng build
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is running into this in 2018, the thing that finally worked for me was to go into the my-app I created with `ng new my-app`, and THEN run `ng serve` This has to do with it needing the dependencies and devDependencies located in `my-app/package.json` instead of `root/package.json`. They are two separate files.

Even if I copied the all the dependencies to my root folder's `package.json`, I would also have to go in and manually change the path locations for the config files and such to go into `my-app/*`.  It is much easier to just go into `my-app/` and run `ng serve` there to let it all work like it is supposed to.

So these steps should work for anyone:

`rm -rf <previous-app>` // Whatever your previous app was called, if you had one.

`sudo rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -f package-lock.json`

`npm install`

`ng new my-app`

`cd my-app`

`ng serve`

Comment: Can you explain what does rm -rf <previous-app> I don't remember if and why I did a `previous-app`
After doing your commands I get a `You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.` error while doing `ng new my-app`

Comment: @Marine1 You cannot create a new Angular app inside of an Angular app. and only run `rm -rf <previous app>` if you had a previous app that is creating this problem. substitute the name of you app in here. `rm -rf` _removes recursively by force the entire directory's contents_

Answer (score 2):

Run the **npm update** after installing all peer dependencies and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, and the reason is

1. when you run `ng new app-name` it will create a new directory with app name and install everything in that.
2. after running the above command, human tendency is to run `ng serve`
   and because your app is in sub directory it will not find package.json and throw the mentioned error.

Solution is pretty simple. just move to the sub directory and then run `ng serve`

Comment: ie., cd ng5 directory

Comment: @AjayTakur directory name will be same as the app name.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same Issue. While running ngserve you should be in the apps directory. To confirm(on GIT BASH : you will have (master) after the directory path at gitbash prompt, if you are at app directory.)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem.

I first ran `npm install @angular/core`.

Then I ran `npm install --save`.

When both installs had successfully completed I ran `npm serve` and received an error saying

```
"Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again."
```

I then deleted my node_modules folder as well as my package-lock.json folder.

After I deleted those folders I ran `npm install --save` once more.

I ran `npm start` and received another error. This error said `Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'`.

I ran `npm install @angular-devkit/core --save`.

Finally, I ran `npm start` and the project started!

Answer (score 1):

You create new project with:

```
ng new firstngapp
```

In your example you are missing `new`. This would create folder, generate files and run `npm install` for you.
It seems that you've created folder but there's no Angular CLI app in it.

And for starting the app use:

```
ng serve
```

`npm start` is only used if you have ejected from cli.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to no avail:

- npm install
- npm update
- ng serve

**npm install -g @angular/cli** worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the required dependancy is not installed.Use this for future reference.

```
npm install @angular/core
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and along with removing the node_modules and reinstalling I needed to remove package-lock.json first.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I tried to run "ng serve" after that I saw some suggetions one of the techie told me to update my npm.I did that as well then I got this screen after entering "ng server"

""Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_module and package-lock.json(if you have one) and 
Run npm install again.""

After performing all the actions now its working correctly...and getting message "Compiled Successfully."

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the ng server from the c:\project\angular-src location. Not just the root of your project.

Comment: OP might not have c:\project\angular-src folder. And no, you answer makes no sense. `ng serve` must be run from the root of the folder, since that's where the `package.json` file defining this script is.

Answer (score 0):

Executing ng new --skip-install PROJECT_NAME and then manually going into the created folder and typing npm install.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3906

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Hence the `npm install`, not **update**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that I followed the cli's advice to switch to yarn package management.

Then while following a tutorial I did `npm install --save bootstrap`, and after that point the error started appearing. Afterwards I did `yarn add xxx` of course and it worked.

To restore the project's state I removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375337/289992) answer and then run `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run 
npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was mixing package managers. My project was generated with Yarn, and after that, I added a couple of dependencies using npm install (this created the package-lock.json with only added dependencies).

Apparently, ng serve used package-lock.json and couldn't find Angular dependencies there. After I started using only Yarn, i.e. yarn add instead of npm install, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

For ng serve you need to be inside that directory

```
ashish@ashish-Inspiron-3521:~/Angular$ ng new FireStore
  create FireStore/README.md (1025 bytes)
  create FireStore/.angular-cli.json (1245 bytes)
  create FireStore/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
  create FireStore/.gitignore (544 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/environments/environment.ts (387 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/index.html (296 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/polyfills.ts (3114 bytes)
  create FireStore/src/styles.css (80 bytes)

ashish@ashish-Inspiron-3521:~/Angular$ ng serve
You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
```

How I solved this using cmd

```
ashish@ashish-Inspiron-3521:~/Angular$ cd FireStore/
```

Now Do cmd

```
ashish@ashish-Inspiron-3521:~/Angular/FireStore$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should be in the newly created YOUR_APP folder before you hit the ng serve command **

Lets start from fresh,

1) `install npm`

2) create a new angular app ( `ng new <YOUR_APP_NAME>` )

3) go to app folder (`cd YOUR_APP_NAME`)

4) `ng serve`

I hope it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem.

1. Step1: `cd projectName`
2. Step2: `npm update`
3. Step3: `ng serve -o`

For example :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have angular.json in the folder where you try to build serve etc.
Maybe it's one level up because of a misplaced npm install.